# Do we have any pattern matching string search ?/

Tags: c, linux, string

I have a following string format.

```
({'BTAddress': <'00:22:58:07:76:9B'>, 'Name': <'Some-Name'>, 'Alias': <'some-Name'>, 'Class': <uint32 12316>, 'Adapter': <objectpath '/org/bluez/3196/hci0'>},)
```

I would like to parse the above string in C. Instead of doing raw parsing, any advice to use  pattern wise parsing ?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to parse a JSON string in C?  If you phrase the problem that way, you might get a different perspective of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/.
You'll have to do some hand work to make it work, but it works fine.

**Note**: the `char` pointer that you pass will be manipulated!!

Comment: strtok seems like the obvious solution, but if he tries to separate each key:value pair by strtok'ing for commas (","), it could get messy if a comma appears within quotes for one of the values in the set.

Comment: I would suggest that `strtok()` is pretty close to "*doing raw parsing*"

Comment: I would start separating the string into key-value tokens. Then you can separate the tokens and just cut away the start and end.
It's pretty raw parsing, but without specifying what kind of string you want to parse.. combining it with regex like omu_nergu suggested looks also fine to me.

Answer (score 1):

Any POSIX-compliant C compiler should provide `<regex.h>`, giving you regular expressions that should be able to help with this.

Comment: Not sure if i am wrong, i looked into regex, and i dont see the way to get key/value method ?.. any Advice ?

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression library is probably what you need.  If you are using the GNU C library that has a [regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html) library, for [pattern matching](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_16.html).  For Win32 compilers, you can use [Regex for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/regex.htm) port of the GNU code.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions are as follows :

```
 A) try using strtok to split the text at ',' and then split the resulting subtexts only once at ':' ,that way you would get the key,value pairs you desire.
 B) use a regEx api under C that would basically solve your issue.
```

Also i might suggest looking for a key value store under C for your parsed text (C++ has one but i really don't know about C)

Comment: Could you kindly provide addition details on key/value in c++?